# Formatting questions

Tags: formatting

I am trying to write my CV as described in:

[Text tabbing in with \> \= and\kill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392885/text-tabbing-in-with-and-kill?noredirect=1#comment976196_392885)

Now I am almost complete I just have a question concerning two issues I find odd.

First of all, I have a line at the header, which I had to make longer to

```
\rule{1.07 \textwidth}{0.5mm}
```

that it is as long as the tabbed text below (uses minipage).

Secondly for two of the headlines of the section, I have distances between the header and its text, which is dramatically long (about three times as long as normal)!

Do you know where that might come from?

The second problem occurs in the section Personal Profile and Interest. I have changed Personal Profile to:

> ```
> > \section{Personal Profile} \begin{tabbing} \hspace{3cm} \= \\ \kill \>
> > \begin{minipage}{\smallertextwidth} {balbla \tikzcircle{1.6pt} next
> > thing  \tikzcircle{1.6pt} etc.} \end{minipage} \end{tabbing}
> ```

with:

```
\newcommand{\tikzcircle}[2][black,fill=black]{\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]\draw[#1,radius=#2] (0,0) circle ;}%
```

I have changed the intererstgroup to:

```
\newcommand{\interestsgroup}[1]{
\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{3cm} \= \hspace{2mm} \= \\ \kill
 #1
\end{tabbing}
\vspace{-10mm}
}
```

I have done all this to have a nearly equal tabbing for the whole document.

That are the changes for both parts. Hope that might give a hint, where this different spacing comes from.

I tried to come as near an mvc as possible...

this is the link for the structure_mvc.tex:

https://pastebin.com/drvj2Vzj

and here the corresponding dump cv: 
https://pastebin.com/4H0nnD5h

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you `\noindent` your `minipage`?  If not, it is indented and could extend past the right margin.  That is perhaps where the `1.07` arises.  However, you need to provide us a self compiling code (MWE) to get an authentic answer.

Comment: @ Steven, Thanks alot. What you discribed sounds, as it would fit. I added a better description of the problem, with example passages... I hope, that makes the problem somewhat clearer. I tried \noindent for the in Personl Profile. But nothing changed there.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). As @StevenB.Segletes suggested, code snippets are useful in explanations, but it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @Welcome to TeX.Se Justed tried to make an mvc.. your comment came faster than I could make one. The length between the ection headers and the section section is even worse hear... (also Problem with Referees) Why aren't they the same? Sorry, that the "mvc" is much to long...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I thought about what you said with \noindent... Problem is: I want the text to be indent, but not to pass the right margin.

Comment: Then the width of the `minipage` must be decreased, from `\textwidth` to `\dimexpr\textwidth-\parindent\relax`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of on part of the problem, the text that writtes of the right margin was to change the width of minipage, which was defined in the structure.tex as

```
% Text width for tabbing environments
\newlength{\smallertextwidth}
\setlength{\smallertextwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\smallertextwidth}{-2cm}
```

I changed the last line to:

```
\addtolength{\smallertextwidth}{-3cm}
```

That solved the textwidth problem, the extra whitespace between Subtitles of a section and it's text is still unsolved.